# Can you change a String object after you create it?

Tags: java

- If you answer "yes", then give an example of how you can change a String.
- If you answer "no", then explain why the Java designers don't let us modify Strings

Comment: homework perchance? I see no attempt...

Answer (score 1):

No.

Strings are immutable by design.  If you want to alter a string, I suggest you look at the StringBuffer class.

Immutable is a design pattern.  As multiple entities can reference an object, immutability ensures that the object you reference has not been altered by some other object that references it.

Comment: why the Java designers don't let us modify Strings

Comment: To avoid unexpected changes in the string value.  If in one block of code (perhaps in thread A), you are referencing a string, while at the same time, thread B is manipulating that string, then thread A would be affected in an unpredictable way - that is, thread A could not guarantee the string value would not change.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot modify a string after you create it.  `String` is an example of an [immutable class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). If you have the following code:

```
String a = "hello";
String b = a;
```

`a` and `b` are now referencing the same object, but there is nothing that you can do to `a` that will change the string that `b` is referencing.  You can only assign `a` to a different string.

I can only speculate about why the Java designers chose to have it this way, but I suspect a major reason is to facilitate code predictability.  If you had something like this.

```
String h = "house";
String hcopy = h;
```

and at some later point you were able to modify `h` in some way like `h.splitInHalf()` that actually changed `h`'s string, that would also affect `hcopy` and make things very frustrating when simple `String` variables changed values without warning.

If you would like a `String`-like structure that you can modify, you can use `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't not,each time you try to change it,a new String object is actually created.If you want to use changable String,use StringBuffer,StringBuilder instead.

There is a String constant pool in memory for better performence.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that's a popular interview question. The objective is to figure out whether the interviewee knows the internals of the `java.lang.String` class.

So to answer the question, by design, Java does not allow to change a String object, those objects are immutable. However, though you should never do it in a real production code, it is technically possible to change a String object using the Reflection API.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str = "Hello world!";
        Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        valueField.setAccessible(true);
        char[] c = (char[]) valueField.get(str);
        c[1] = 'a';
        System.out.println(str); //prints Hallo world! 
    }
}
```

As is often said, Java will let you shoot yourself in the foot after you use a magic spell of "import java.lang.reflect.*;"